# How do I find a specific caracter already written on the console and set the cursor position there? C#

Tags: c#, console-application

Im reading a text from a file and printing it on the console.

I need to set the cursor position where the letter S is.

I have different files and the position of the letter S may change.

How can I find where the position of the letter S is and then start trying to find a way out of the maze?

[Example of a maze file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsDEW.png)

I just need some help with ideas on how could I maybe find a solution, no need to solve the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set Cursor use functions `CursorTop` and `CursorLeft` or `Console.SetCursorPosition()`. To Calculate the position use the content of your matrix that represents a maze, which you've saved during loading data from file(s).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didnt think that the text loaded on the screen was actually an accessible array. You helped me to understand that concept and to find a start point to solve my problem.